# Frob_p under class field theory for cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: number-theory, class-field-theory

Why does $$p^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_p^\times \subseteq \mathbb{A}^\times/\mathbb{Q}$$

go to $Frob_p$ for the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty})/\mathbb{Q}$.

[image]

Comment: The ideles Artin map can be obtained in two ways: from the Artin map on ideals, or from a character of $(\mathbb{Z}/f\mathbb{Z})^\times$, equating the two (so that the mix is trivial on the diagonal embedding of $\Bbb{Q}^\times$) is the point of class field theory. For cyclotomic fields (and their subextensions) it is relatively easy. The "mixed" version can be assembled from the local artin maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I see. the map. The isomorphism $\mathbb{A}^\times/\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{R}^\times_{\geq 0} \times \prod \mathbb{Z}_l^\times$ basically drops the "rational" part of an idele (because we are moding out by $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{A}^\times/\mathbb{Q}$, and so $p^{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ goes to $(1, 1, ..., p^{-1}, 1, 1 ..) \equiv (p, p, \ldots, 1, p, ..)$ which goes to $p$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/f\mathbb{Z})^\times$ which is what $Frob$ goes to.